# Installation of cuda 11.02 driver component on ubuntu 20.04 using downloaded "run" file failed

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I downloaded the *runfile (local)* for *ubuntu 20.04* from *Nvidia Developer* site as shown [Nvida Local runfile](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=runfile_local)

[image]

Then followed the instructions to run the program:

```
sudo sh cuda_11.3.0_465.19.01_linux.run
```

The installation failed: here is the error in */var/log/cuda-installer.log* :

```
[INFO]: Driver installation detected by command: apt list --installed | grep -e nvidia-driver-[0-9][0-9][0-9] -e nvidia-[0-9][0-9][0-9]
[INFO]: Cleaning up window
[INFO]: Complete
[INFO]: Checking compiler version...
[INFO]: gcc location: /usr/bin/gcc

[INFO]: gcc version: gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

[INFO]: Initializing menu
[INFO]: Setup complete
[INFO]: Components to install:
[INFO]: Driver
[INFO]: 465.19.01
[INFO]: Executing NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-465.19.01.run --ui=none --no-questions --accept-license --disable-nouveau --no-cc-version-check --install-libglvnd  2>&1
[INFO]: Finished with code: 256
[ERROR]: Install of driver component failed.
[ERROR]: Install of 465.19.01 failed, quitting
```

There are no further indications of what failed or instructions of what to do. What can/should be done next to move forward?

Answer (score 7):

Besides the CUDA log file, there is also a driver log file, which will be created typically at `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` .

The CUDA installer calls the driver installer, which writes log of the driver installation in that file, so when the driver installer fails, you may get more details about the error from there.

Source: [NVidia developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/info-finished-with-code-256-error-install-of-driver-component-failed/107661)

By the way, in my case, the driver installer failed [because the X server was running](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/465.24.02/README/installdriver.html#BeforeYouBegin89f39). Stopping the X server before the driver installation fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thx I'll look into these

Comment: I also have issues with failures due to the X server running. To stop the X server I've used the answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441811/199224, which just involves running: `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` for all details.

In my case, secure boot was enabled so it stopped installation.

> The kernel module failed to load. Secure boot is enabled on this
> system, so this is likely because it was not signed by a key that is
> trusted by the kernel. Please try installing the driver again, and
> sign the kernel module when prompted to do so.

Use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled) link to install with secure boot.